# Fórmula para buscar en un rango en excel de una hoja y pasar su valor asociado a otra hoja

Tags: excel

En una hoja tengo un rango lista de estudiantes con su cédula y notas, en otro se pretende calcular el promedio, teniendo en cuenta que no están en el mismo orden, ¿cuál es la fórmula para buscar el valor asociado(cédula en este caso) en el rango de una hoja y cuando coincida tomar las notas para calcular el promedio en otra hoja?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ``BUSCARV`` , saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la hoja donde tienes las notas se llama **Notas** y la hoja donde tienes que hallar el promedio se llama **Promedio**.
El promedio se halla de la siguiente forma:
`=suma(a;b;c;d)/4`

Para hallar los valores de a,b,c y d haremos uso de [BUSCARV](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/funci%C3%B3n-buscarv-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) que es una de las funciones que tiene excel para encontrar elementos de una tabla o rango de una fila.
Entonces hallemos los valores.
a=BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;3;0)
b=BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;4;0)
c=BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;5;0)
d=BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;6;0)
Si juntamos todo lo descrito anteriormente y pegamos en la celda **C2** tendremos lo  solicitado.

```
=SUMA(BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;3;0);BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;4;0);BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;5;0);BUSCARV(A2;Notas!$A$2:$F$7;6;0))/4
```

Answer (score 0):

Sinceramente, la opción más fácil que veo es calcular el promedio en la propia hoja de notas y luego traerlo con un BUSCARV:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El promedio lo he calculado con `=PROMEDIO(I2:L2)` y para llevarlo al otro lado hice `=BUSCARV(A2;$G$2:$M$5;7;FALSO)`

Fácil y sencillo.

Si quieres evitar usar una columna auxiliar, necesitas algo más complejo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`=SUMAPRODUCTO($I$2:$L$5*--($G$2:$G$5=A2))/4`

Honestamente, si tienes poca experiencia en Excel te recomendaría la primera solución que puse.